# How to get origin from POSIXct object

Tags: r, datetime, posix, posixct

I have a function like so:

```
foo = function(time_in){
    # code here that changes POSIXct to numeric
    time_out = as.POSIXct(time_in, origin = '1970-01-01')
}
```

where the user enters `time_in` as a POSIXct object. I use this parameter in a linear model (`lm()`) which spits my value back out as a numeric. Finally, I want to convert it back to a POSIXct object for my user. The problem is, `as.POSIXct()` requires an `origin` which is typically Jan 1, 1970 UTC. But what if my user is working off a different origin? How can I extract the origin from `time_in` to use it as an argument for `time_out`?

I have looked for documentation on how to get the origin, but `str(time_in)` and `attributes(time_in)` don't give me anything and I haven't found much else. Since this will be in a package, I'd like to stick with base R functions to limit the number of dependencies needed.

Comment: If it's an `as.POSIXct` object, it's origin is `1970-01-01` as far as I am aware. It doesn't store an origin. From `?as.POSIXct` - "*...the origin of
     time for the ‘"POSIXct"’ class, ‘1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC’...*

Comment: For both `Date` and `POSIXct` class, identifying the origin should be as simple as `x - as.numeric (x)`. For `POSIXct`, this should be moot, since the origin is always 1970-01-01

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I thought that was just the default origin, not the only possible. That would explain why I couldn't find anything on it. Thanks.

Comment: "1970-01-01" is not the only possible entry. Excel on Windows uses "1899-12-30" and on Mac "1904-01-01"

Comment: This confused me too, because origin is required when calling `as.POSIXct` with a number, so I thought origin must be stored. No, it's just being pedantic and you must specify 1970 for it to do what you expect.