# For loop dates without losing date format

Tags: r, date, for-loop, format

I am trying to use a for loop to extract dates from an SQL query in R. Currently I have:

```
StartDate<-"2017-07-01"
EndDate<- "2017-07-05"
dates<-seq(as.POSIXct(StartDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), as.POSIXct(EndDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), by='days')

for (f in dates){
. 
. Code here that is inside for loop
.
}
```

My issue is that does not come out in a date format as in Dates. How do I get f in the same format as StartDate and EndDate?

Comment: Can't you just: `for (f in as.character(dates)) {}`?

Comment: try `as.list` wrapper around dates in your `for` loop

Answer (score 7):

Let's try `as.list()` wrapper so that 'Date' format is preserved in `for` loop

```
for (f in as.list(dates)){
 print(str(f))
}
```

Comment: This works better than what I was doing but for some reason it skips half of my code out in the loop? Unsure as to why...Maybe it's my code? Is there a limit to what can go into a for loop?

Comment: I don't think that `for` loop has any iteration limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
StartDate<-"2017-07-01"
EndDate<- "2017-07-05"
dates<-seq(as.POSIXct(StartDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), as.POSIXct(EndDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), by='days')

for (f in dates){
print(as.POSIXct(f,origin = "1970-01-01"))
}
```

Comment: Why is the origin "1960-01-01"?

Comment: You can change it but usually we use a default date which is : 1970-01-01 ( i made a mistake). You can see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690722/how-to-get-origin-from-posixct-object